# DirectX immediate context on different thread from message pump

Tags: c++, windows, direct3d

If I call `CoInitializeEx()` with the flag COINIT_APARTMENT_THREADED, is it wise to create and use all my Direct3D objects on a different thread than the one that calls `PeekMessage()` or `GetMessage()`?  Does this have a performance hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should make sure your main windows thread pump, DXGI calls, and immediate context usage are all on the same thread. See "[DirectX Graphics Infrastructure (DXGI): Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)".

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is because of Present() blocking (which I have no control over as far as I know), which is very annoying because I need access to the messages that occur while the frame is being rendered on the GPU / between vblanks.  I'm using deferred contexts for all drawing.  Would not obeying this affect the performance of other threads, or just the Present() thread?